# How to use MemoryBarrier? Ways to safe Atomicity operations?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

While I was learning threading memory barrier (fences) seems really not easy to understand, here in my case I want employee **10 threads** simultaneously increase a Int32 number: **x** by 100 times at each (x++), and will get result 10 * 100 = 1000.

So this is actually an atomicity problem, and what I know so far there are a number of ways to achieve that - limited in **concurrent** ways:

1. Interlocked.Increment
2. exclusive lock (lock, monitor, Mutex, Semaphore, etc.)
3. ReadWriteLockSlim

> If there are more better ways please kindly guide me, I tried to use a volatile read/write but failed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    Thread.VolatileRead(ref x);
    Thread.VolatileWrite(ref x, x + 1);
}
```

My investigation code is tidied below:

```
private const int MaxThraedCount = 10;
private Thread[] m_Workers = new Thread[MaxThraedCount];
private volatile int m_Counter = 0;
private Int32 x = 0;

protected void btn_DoWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxThraedCount; i++)
    {
        m_Workers[i] = new Thread(IncreaseNumber) { Name = "Thread " + (i + 1) };
        m_Workers[i].Start();
    }
}

void IncreaseNumber()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            Interlocked.Increment(ref x);

        // Increases Counter and decides whether or not sets the finish signal
        m_Counter++;
        if (m_Counter == MaxThraedCount)
        {
            // Print finish information on UI
            m_Counter = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I **use Memory Barrier to replace Interlocked**, since "[All of Interlocked’s methods generate a full fence.](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Interlocked)", I tried to modify the increase loop as below but failed, I don't understand why...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    x++;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory barrier just keeps memory operations from moving from one side of the barrier to the other. Your issue is this:

1. Thread A reads the value of X.
2. Thread B reads the value of X.
3. Thread A adds one to the value it read.
4. Thread B adds one to the value it read.
5. Thread A writes back the value it calculated.
6. Thread B writes back the value it calculated.

Oops, two increments only added one. Memory barriers are not atomic operations and they are not locks. They just enforce ordering, not atomicity.

Unfortunately, the x86 architecture does not offer any atomic operations that don't include a full fence. It is what it is. On the bright side, the full fence is heavily optimized. (For example, it does not ever lock any bus.)

Comment: "Memory barriers are not atomic operations and they are not locks. They just enforce ordering, not atomicity." This makes sense! Thanks!  At the other hand, could you kindly guide me whether there are other ways to achieve my goal: "Correctly get the result!", ignoring the performance, just enumerates all possible solutions:)

Comment: There are some silly ways. You could have one instance of the variable for each thread and have each thread increment/decrement its own instance without a lock. You would then need to sum them all to get the value. But I think you'll find that you should just take the cost of the barrier, and if it's too high, redesign so you don't manipulate shared state so often.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: That isn't a silly way. Keeping counts per-thread is the optimum way when you only read it rarely. The Linux kernel uses that technique.

Comment: Thank you! I think in real development, do simple x++ in each thread is much more efficient than using interlocked on a shared because there is no overhead on creating full memory fences in every thread. However, I posted the question was asking all possible solutions simultaneously operating on shared variable and make sure atomic safe, so in fact I ignore this solution:)

Answer (score 2):

You can't "use `MemoryBarrier` to replace `Interlocked`". They are two different tools.

Use `MemoryBarrier`, `volatile` etc to control re-ordering of reads and writes. Use `Interlocked`, `lock` etc for atomicity.

(Besides, are you aware that calling `MemoryBarrier` also generates a full fence*, as do `VolatileRead` and `VolatileWrite`? So if you're trying to avoid `Interlocked`, `lock` etc for performance reasons, there's a good chance that your alternatives will be *less* performant as well as *more* likely to be broken.)

<sub>**In the standard Microsoft CLR, at least. I'm not sure about Mono etc.*</sub>